# Bash script python pyenv

Tags: bash, pyenv-virtualenv

I use pyenv in my work and try to automate activation pyenv via bash script.

Normally i use below commands to activate it (it works well):

```
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"


pyenv activate venv
```

I try to use bash script to automate it via bash script

Bash script (mybash_script)

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

pyenv activate venv
```

then i do

```
chmod +x ./mybash_script
```

But when i try to execute it - it doesn't activate pyenv. What i'm doing wrong why it is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Your Bash script activates your Python environment and exits.

Try running it with `source mybash_script`.

Comment: it works with source, but why it doesn't work without?

Comment: It works but you never see it because when you run the script, it starts a new shell process. When the script is done, the process exits. You return to your old shell.